# No module named pandas datareader even after fresh install

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, conda, spyder

Any idea why I get this error message even after installing and updating pandas_datareader?

I have installed Pandas datareader using the following command at a conda command prompt:

> conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader

It tells me the following:

> The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority
>   channel:   pandas-datareader                               pkgs/main
>   --> anaconda

But when I try to run the code I get the following error message:

> from pandas_datareader import data, wb ModuleNotFoundError: No module
>   named 'pandas_datareader'

Here is the code I am using. I got it from this website: https://amunategui.github.io/market-profile/index.html

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from collections import defaultdict

def Print_Market_Profile(symbol, height_precision = 1, 
    frequency='m', start_date=None, end_date=None):

    # We will look at stock prices over the past year
    if start_date == None:
        # get a year's worth of data from today
        start_date = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=365.24)
        # set date to first of month
        start_date = start_date.replace(day=1)
    if end_date == None:
        end_date = datetime.date.today() 

    fin_prod_data = pdr.get_data_google(symbol.upper(), start_date, end_date)
    fin_prod_data[('High')] = fin_prod_data[('High')] * height_precision
    fin_prod_data[('Low')] = fin_prod_data[('Low')] * height_precision
    fin_prod_data = fin_prod_data.round({'Low': 0, 'High': 0})  

    time_groups = fin_prod_data.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq=frequency))['Adj Close'].mean()
    current_time_group_index=0

    from collections import defaultdict
    mp = defaultdict(str)
    char_mark = 64

    # build dictionary with all needed prices
    tot_min_price=min(np.array(fin_prod_data['Low']))
    tot_max_price=max(np.array(fin_prod_data['High']))
    for price in range(int(tot_min_price), int(tot_max_price)):
        mp[price]+=('\t')

    # add max price as it will be ignored in for range loop above
    mp[tot_max_price] = '\t' + str(time_groups.index[current_time_group_index])[5:7] + '/' + str(time_groups.index[current_time_group_index])[3:4]

    for x in range(0, len(fin_prod_data)):
        if fin_prod_data.index[x] > time_groups.index[current_time_group_index]:
            # new time period
            char_mark=64
            # buffer and tab all entries
            buffer_max = max([len(v) for k,v in mp.iteritems()])
            current_time_group_index += 1
            for k,v in mp.iteritems():
                mp[k] += (chr(32) * (buffer_max - len(mp[k]))) + '\t'
            mp[tot_max_price] += str(time_groups.index[current_time_group_index])[5:7] + '/' + str(time_groups.index[current_time_group_index])[3:4]


        char_mark += 1
        min_price=fin_prod_data['Low'][x]
        max_price=fin_prod_data['High'][x]
        for price in range(int(min_price), int(max_price)):
            mp[price]+=(chr(char_mark))

    sorted_keys = sorted(mp.keys(), reverse=True)
    for x in sorted_keys:
        # buffer each list
        print(str("{0:.2f}".format((x * 1.0) / height_precision)) + ': \t' + ''.join(mp[x]))

def main():
    # customize ingestion of agruments to handle
    # frequency: http://nullege.com/codes/search/pandas.TimeGrouper

    if (len(sys.argv[1:]) == 1):
        symbol = sys.argv[1:][0]
        Print_Market_Profile(symbol)
    elif (len(sys.argv[1:]) == 2):
        symbol = sys.argv[1:][0]
        height_precision = float(sys.argv[1:][1])
        Print_Market_Profile(symbol, height_precision)
    elif (len(sys.argv[1:]) == 3):
        symbol = sys.argv[1:][0]
        height_precision = float(sys.argv[1:][1])
        frequency = sys.argv[1:][2]
        Print_Market_Profile(symbol, height_precision, frequency)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the python interpreter you use to run your script is the one from the conda environment you installed to?

Comment: I am running the command from the same anaconda prompt which I used for the package update. So Im guessing its the same?

Comment: Try to add `print(sys.executable)` after `import sys` to confirm

Comment: Thanks but still the same: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

Comment: What is the output you get from the added line?

Comment: runfile('C:/Dev/Spyder/TPO.py', wdir='C:/Dev/Spyder')
C:\Users\grant\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe